# Wordpress get unique Custom Field values only

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I am working on a Wordpress site that displays a number of Projects stored in Custom Post Types. Each Custom Post includes two Custom Fields (amongst others) "Project Name" and "Project Color". There may be several Custom Posts about a particular "Project Name".

I want to create a legend (a key) of all the projects which lists the "Project Names" and "Project Colors" taken from the custom field values above.

So for example, I have 3 projects called "Bananas" whose color is "Yellow", 6 called "Oranges" whose color is "orange" and 4 called "Apples" whose color is "green". My legend (key) should display one banana in yellow, one orange in orange and one apple in green.

Of course if I use the loop it displays 3 bananas, 6 oranges and 4 apples. How can I display just a list of the Project Names and Project Colors?

I've looked at three methods, a custom taxonomy, checking for duplicates in an array and using [`GROUP BY`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) as a filter on `posts_groupby`.

`GROUP BY` seems like the right way to go but I can't get it to do anything. The furthest I got was putting this in my functions.php...

```
function sort_legend ( $groupby ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $groupby .= "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'Color' "; 
    return $groupby;
}
```

...and applying it as a filter around my Query object...

```
<?php  add_filter('posts_groupby', 'sort_legend'); ?>
<?php if ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) while ($myQuery->have_posts() ) : $myQuery->the_post(); ?>
<?php remove_filter('posts_groupby', 'sort_legend'); ?>
```

...but I still have multiple entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution...

Delete the 'Project Colors' and 'Project Names' custom fields from the custom template, (sigh), register a custom taxonomy called 'Project Classes' and assign the newly registered taxonomy to the custom post type, see [here](http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/taxonomy/). In the Wordpress interface, give each custom post its appropriate 'Project Class' bananas, apples etc, again explained in the above link.

However there is still the problem of how to show a color key for each custom taxonomy entry. I reused the Project Class names as style sheet names so I could give each style name a background-color. However the real Project Class names have capital letters and spaces which need to be removed to make them style sheet friendly.

Add a php function `rename_projects` in functions.php that amends the spaces and capital letters in the 'Project Class' taxonomy name and makes it suitable for a css style name, I used...

```
// Rename Projects custom field for css styles
function rename_projects($sProjectName) {
$sFind = ' '; 
$sReplace = '-';
$sAmended = mb_strtolower(str_replace( $sFind, $sReplace, $sProjectName ));
return $sAmended;
}
```

Now you can use your Project Class names as style sheet names.

Next, in your page template display your custom taxonomy thus...

```
<?php
    $args=array(
    'taxonomy' => 'projectclass',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $categories=get_categories($args);
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $sColorName = rename_projects($category->name); // To lower case and replace spaces
        echo '<div class="legend-color ' . $sColorName . '"></div> // Color style name
        <div class="legend-project">' . $category->name . '</div>'; // Taxonomy name
    } 
?>
```

So now for example a `$category->name` "My First Project" has a corresponding style sheet name `my-first-project` which you can add to your style sheet and style. Note that in the `<div class="legend-color '` I am *adding* the style name to the existing class so the resulting class will be "legend-color my-first-project": i.e. two styles. The hard coded class "legend-color" holds all the style attributes except background-color which is in `$sColorName`.

Working fine here.